# How to get hex index of a special char represented in debian's less as <D5> or similar?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, utf-8, hex

When I open my file with debian's `less` I can see that some of the chars are represented as `<D5>`:

[image]

or `<93>`:

[image]

My question is how to translate this code to hex?

Additional info: the encoding of my file is `mac_roman`, my console encoding is `utf-8`

Comment: Well, I’d say `<D5>` _is already_ hex. Could you explain more clearly what you want to do?

Comment: I just want to know how to replace this and other "incorrect" characters. My scenario is: a. I open file and find `<..>` symbols; b. I convert those symbols' codes to hex; c. I replace those symbols to other, which is in utf-8 [list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. First of all the file must be converted to utf-8:

```
iconv -f macintosh -t UTF-8 < INPUT_FILE_PATH
```

Now I can replace the non-UTF chars. An example in python3:

```
replace_table = {
    ord('’'): "´",
    ord('ì'): '«',
    ord('î'): '»',
    # to find new spec chars: iconv -f macintosh -t UTF-8 < INPUT_FILE_PATH
}
with open('filename', 'r',  encoding='mac_roman', newline='') as f:
    [l.translate(replace_table) for l in f.readlines()]
```